# Service will be restart after I remove app from recent task

Tags: android, service, background-service

I'm developing an app for get user location in background service.
My scenario is like below

1. user go to an activity and run a background service.
2. service must get user location in period 5000 Millisecond and send
   this data to caller activity and show to user.
3. user delete application from recent tasks.
4. service commonly must collect user location data period 5000
   Millisecond.
5. when user go to back application must see yourself walked locations
   from start to current location.

I searched about this in google and I find answers, but when I use their solutions my service will be restarted after I come back to application and send to me empty data when application was destroyed.

**MyService**

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


        return START_STICKY; 

}
```

**My Activity**

```
private BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

 @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
               do stuff;
            }
        }
    };

@Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(
                MyService.NOTIFICATION));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Tracking service that track your location with fused location api and which starts also when app closed and send data to firebase you can track the way you want

```
public class TrackingService extends Service implements LocationListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constant.DISPATCHER_LOCATION);

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private static String TAG = "MyService";

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constant.TBL_USER);

        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");

        if (isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()) {
            createLocationRequest();
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();

            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        }

    }

    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateLocationRequest");

        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY).setInterval(7000).setFastestInterval(5000);
        ;
    }

    public void startTracking() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            startLocationUpdates(getApplicationContext());
//            Toast.makeText(this, "start tracking", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }

    public void stopTracking() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            try {
                Log.d(TAG, "onStop fired ..............");
                stopLocationUpdates();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ref.getParent().child(Constant.TBL_USER).child(new SaveInSharedPreference(this).getString(Constant.CURRENT_USER)).child("dispatcher").setValue(false);

                Intent i = new Intent(this, UserWelcome.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    }

    protected void startLocationUpdates(Context context) {

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // TODO: Consider calling
                //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
                // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
                //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                //                                          int[] grantResults)
                // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
                // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
                return;
            }
            PendingResult<Status> pendingResult = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

            Log.d(TAG, "Location update started ..............: ");

        }

    }

    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        try {
            // stop update location
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, this);
            Log.d(TAG, "Location update stopped .......................");
//            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
            Log.d(TAG, "isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            ref.getParent().child(Constant.TBL_USER).child(new SaveInSharedPreference(this).getString(Constant.CURRENT_USER)).child("dispatcher").setValue(false);
            Intent i = new Intent(this, UserWelcome.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand");

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        try {
            stopTracking();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ref.getParent().child(Constant.TBL_USER).child(new SaveInSharedPreference(this).getString(Constant.CURRENT_USER)).child("dispatcher").setValue(false);
            Intent i = new Intent(this, UserWelcome.class);
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
        Constant.CURRENT_LOCATION = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        if (!new SaveInSharedPreference(getApplicationContext()).getString(Constant.CURRENT_USER).equals("no")) {
            mDatabase.child(new SaveInSharedPreference(getApplicationContext()).getString(Constant.CURRENT_USER)).child("lat").setValue(location.getLatitude());
            mDatabase.child(new SaveInSharedPreference(getApplicationContext()).getString(Constant.CURRENT_USER)).child("lon").setValue(location.getLongitude());

            if (new SaveInSharedPreference(this).getString(Constant.ACCEPT_ORDER).equals("no")) {
                mDatabase.child(new SaveInSharedPreference(getApplicationContext()).getString(Constant.CURRENT_USER)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        firebaseUserModal firebaseUserModal = dataSnapshot.getValue(firebaseUserModal.class);
                        if (firebaseUserModal.isDispatcher()) {
                            GeoFire geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
                            geoFire.setLocation(new SaveInSharedPreference(getApplicationContext()).getString(Constant.CURRENT_USER), new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                                    if (error != null) {
                                        System.err.println("There was an error saving the location to GeoFire: " + error);
                                    } else {
                                        System.out.println("Location saved on server successfully!");
                                    }
                                }

                            });
                        } else {
                            mDatabase.getParent().child(Constant.DISPATCHER_LOCATION)
                                    .child(new SaveInSharedPreference(getApplicationContext())
                                            .getString(Constant.CURRENT_USER))
                                    .removeValue();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onConnected - isConnected ...............: " + mGoogleApiClient.isConnected());
        startTracking();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed: " + connectionResult.toString());
    }

    private boolean isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() {
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        if (ConnectionResult.SUCCESS == status) {
            return true;
        } else {
            try {

                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, (Activity) getApplicationContext(), 0).show();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e("error", ex.getMessage());
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```